# How many simulations should be at least applied in Monte Carlo Simulations

Tags: monte-carlo

I have a question regarding the minimum number of simulations need to be applied in a Monte Carlo simulation for n factors. For example, I have a portfolio with 1000 stocks, to calculate VaR through Monte Carlo simulation. How many simulations at least I need to run to make sure the model is producing statistically legitimate results?

Is there some rule or closed-form formula I could apply to determine the number of simulations?

Comment: You determine by the square root law

Comment: Simulations are a random  process so there is always a chance that the result is wrong. Increasing the number of replications decreases that chance, but the chance never reaches 0. So any rule is just a trade-off between the time you want to spent on the simulation and the chance of an error of a certain magnitude. You are better of making that tradeoff yourself than rely on such a rule.